# xampp - remove directory name from the base url

Tags: xampp

I'm trying to use XAMPP and I would like the directory name to be ***removed*** from the home URL. I created a directory named `wordpress-gatsby` in my `htdocs` folder and I attain the result shown in the image below.

[image]

I have a path of `http://localhost/wordpress-gatsby`, but I would like the home URL to be `http://localhost:PORT/`, *or* `wordpress-gatsby.local`.

[image]

The image above shows the directory structure of the new WordPress install. I have the `wordpress-gatsby` folder in my `htdocs` folder where I serve my WordPress website.

I'm trying to follow a YouTube tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etii9yp1J6s) and I noticed the instructor doesn't have a trailing *directory name* like I do in my case.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the database,

find the wp-options table,

then search 'home' and 'site-url' and change them to the url you want.